# Screen capture and playback

Tags: c#, wpf, screen-capture

I'm currently using CopyFromScreen from System.Drawing.Graphics in my C# WPF application to continuously take screenshots from the 2nd monitor of a dual monitor environment. These screenshots (Bitmap class) are than displayed via my WPF application on (parts of) my 1st monitor.

However using this approach I'm currently having major performance problems.
What can do to improve the performance in this situation? Are there other libraries (DirectX?) which I can use for capturing and displaying to achieve better performance?

Basically the solution need to be able to capture (parts of) a monitor screen (secondary monitor) and display them in realtime in my application window (on the primary monitor). There is no need to encode or store the data on disk however - I just want to capture and replay instantly.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Do you know that CopyFromScreen is the performance bottleneck?

Comment: I've benchmarked this - so yes. I get about 22fps running only the capture on a single thread using an i7 CPU. I would like to get to about 60fps (if possible with decrease in CPU utilization).

Comment: The benchmark also effects the performs of other application - e.g. dragging windows around is not smooth when I run the benchmark/application.